# Scripts in screen window of their own without quitting when script completes

Tags: gnu-screen

I have been trying to write a custom .screenrc file TEST as follows

```
startup_message off
vbell off
caption always "%{= bb}%{+b w}%n %h %=%t %c"
hardstatus alwayslastline "%-Lw%{= BW}%50>%n%f* %t%{-}%+Lw%<"
activity "Activity in %t(%n)"
shell -/bin/bash
chdir /path1
screen -t WINDOW1 bash -c 'MYSCRIPT1'
chdir /path2
screen -r WINDOW1 bash -c 'MYSCRIPT2'
```

I am running this script as follows

```
screen -c TEST
```

What I am trying to achieve is execute a screen command that spawns two windows in two different directory paths and in each of them two different commands/scripts should be run.

but using this code my screen immediately terminates which is the default behavior.

I want that screen windows should not be terminated rather they should come back to the directory path1 directory path2 respectively once the command terminates in each of these screen windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this as follows. Written a startup script called STARTSCRIPT with below content

```
screen -d -m -S SESSIONNAME

screen -X -S SESSIONNAME -p 0 -t WINDOW0
screen -X -S SESSIONNAME screen -t WINDOW1 1

echo "Trying to start memcached...."
screen -X -S SESSIONNAME -p 1 stuff "memcached
"
echo 'Memcached started....'

echo "Trying to start MYSCRIPT1...."
screen -X -S SESSIONNAME screen -t MYSCRIPT1 2
screen -X -S SESSIONNAME -p 2 stuff "cd /path1; ./MYSCRIPT1
"
echo 'MYSCRIPT1 started....'

echo "Trying to start MYSCRIPT2...."
screen -X -S SESSIONNAME screen -t MYSCRIPT2 3
screen -X -S SESSIONNAME -p 3 stuff "cd /path2; ./MYSCRIPT2
"
echo 'MYSCRIPT2 started....'
```

It is important to note double quotes(") on the next line of the command, without it command will not execute.

Also I moved screen hard status settings to its own ~/.screenrc file so that every screen window created looks like a tab inside screen session.

```
startup_message off
vbell off
caption always "%{= bb}%{+b w}%n %h %=%t %c"
hardstatus alwayslastline "%-Lw%{= BW}%50>%n%f* %t%{-}%+Lw%<"
activity "Activity in %t(%n)"
shell -/bin/bash
```

I executed the STARTSCRIPT as follows

```
$./STARTSCRIPT
```

It gave me the desired output of running commands in their own screen window and these window do not terminate even after the command finishes.